# Cumulative Values on Missing Data Quicksight

Tags: visualization, amazon-quicksight

I'm trying to create a cumulative quarterly count divided by week. I have the underlying table that looks like this:

| Date | Id |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | X |
| 02/01/2022 | Y |

The result is this

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tmFA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tmFA.png)

There are some white spaces due to particular weeks where there are no data. I would like to fill these blank spaces with the value of the week before (as it should be on a cumulative count) and with zero if it's the first week of the quarter.
Is there a way to solve this problem without creating any support table or any "fake data" to avoid the cell to be blank?